# Java dependency unable to find its own resources - code running in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My lambda code uses a dependency that loads its own resources using `ClassOfDependency.class.getResourceAsStream("/filename.jks")`. This works fine when I create a simple main that consumes such dependency, but when I deploy this code to a lambda, it throws an error saying that it cannot find the "/filename.txt". Am I missing something here? The "filename.jsk" is in src/resources/, where resources has been marked in IntelliJ as a resource directory.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried opening your JAR file with an archive explorer to see where the resource is located, if at all?

Comment: Yes, I tried, and the file is there in the resources folder. I ran "jar xf foo.jar"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it - the following method takes in `fileName` and returns `File`.

```
private File getSampleSourceFile(String fileName) {
    try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL url = classLoader.getResource(fileName);

        if(url == null) {
            logger.log("unable to find " + fileName + " in the resource");
            return null;
        }

        File txtFile = File.createTempFile("sample_" + System.currentTimeMillis(), ".txt");
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(url.openStream(), txtFile);

        return txtFile;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log("failed to load file: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

As for the file location, I have my `res` folder outside of `src` folder. I'm not sure what IDE you use to build Jar artifacts but I use IntelliJ IDEA. Here's a screenshot of my module that shows jar package folder hierarchy.

[image]

**Note:**
If you want `InputStream` instead of `File`, you can just return `url.openStream()` instead of converting `InputStream` into a `File`.